# com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.out.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write

Tags: java, jax-rs, squid

We have a JavaAdapter which uses JAX-WS to upload a file from mobile client to backend

While trying to upload a small file of size 300kb it works fine. But the file size is more the 500KB its falling with the below error.

Checked the connectiontmeout and responsetimeout property and its set to 3 mints.

I have a SQUID proxy and set the #Squid configuration directive reply_body_max_size to 10 MB, But by default is no limit.

SQUID access logs smaller file

> 1458569508.679    334 10.17.108.140 TCP_MISS/200 1327 POST http://localhost:60211/ws/MxCUOEECASE.WSD.wsdCASEEEAppMobileSF/MxCUOEECASE_WSD_wsdCASEEEAppMobileSF_Port - DIRECT/209.164.221.165 text/xml

SQUID access logs larger file

> 1458573239.585     11 10.16.237.212 NONE/501 4181 POST http://localhost:60211/ws/MxCUOEECASE.WSD.wsdCASEEEAppMobileSF/MxCUOEECASE_WSD_wsdCASEEEAppMobileSF_Port - NONE/- text/html

By squid access log its clear that the large file request is not forwarding to the backend and its fail before making the request: http://pastebin.com/E9LQPUTg

Comment: Issue is origin from Squid Proxy. This post help to fix the issue.   https://alpacapowered.wordpress.com/2014/05/08/squid-and-chunked-transfer-encoding-shenanigans/

Comment: Please write a full answer instead of a comment.